# Repeating words in python from files

Tags: python, if-statement, text, function

I am a beginner in python, so  I apologize if the code looks bad.  In an assignment, I have to write a function that has 2 parameters.  First parameter, the input reads a file, and the second one is an output file.  For each line in the input file, the function should write the word on the output file that appears more than once.

```
def repeat(fileIn, fileOut):
    fileIn(open(fileIn, 'r')
    fileOut(open(fileOut,'w')
    content = fileIn.read()
    for word in fileIn:
        if word in content:
           outF.write()
    return content
```

when I executed the function, either nothing happened or it returned a syntax error

Comment: The first thing is that you have the closing parenthesis missing on `open` lines.

Comment: Showing us the syntax errors may help too.

Comment: @devnull No, he didn't miss a closing paranthesis. He missed an `=` sign to put the `open` statement into a handle.

Comment: @devnull `fileIn = open(fileIn, 'r')` makes more sense than `fileIn(open(fileIn, 'r'))` don't you think? Especially considering the fact that he's trying to use `fileIn.read()` pointing towards him trying to use `fileIn` as a file-handle?

Comment: @Torxed Yes, it does, of course!

Comment: @devnull Sorry if i came off blunt :) Ment no disrespect or harm! Low on blood suguar over here :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def repeat(fileIn, fileOut):
    fileIn = open(fileIn, 'r')
    fileOut = open(fileOut,'w')
    content = fileIn.read()
    for word in content.split(' '):
        if content.count(word) > 1:
           fileOut.write()
    return content
```

## Your problems were

You didn't use `=` between `fileIn` and `open`, I don't know why you didn't do it.. typ-o?
`open` returns a file-handle which you can do operations on, such as `read`.. In order to put this handle into a variable you use `=`, not `fileIn(open(...))`.

Secondly, you didn't split the `content` into words, doing `for word in content:` could be more accurately describe by renaming the variable to: `for character in content:` because what you do is loop each character of the string when doing a `for` operation on a string. There for you must use `split` to divide the string into a list like so: `["this", "was", "once", "a", "string"]`

Third, you tried `outF.write`, `outF` was never defined.. You called it `fileOut`..

## Now, some enhancement and best practices

Also, try rewriting it to better match best-practices (which was made for just this particular scenario where you forget to close files leaving you with open filehandles):

```
def repeat(fileIn, fileOut):
    with open(fileOut, 'w') as fileOut: # Normally, you don't reuse variable names like this..
        with open(fileIn, 'r') as fileIn:
            content = fileIn.read()
        for word in content.split(' '):
            if content.count(word) > 1:
                fileOut.write()
    return content
```

Note however that this will leave you with words written twice to the new output file because as you loop through each word counting the occurances, the next time you bump into a word it will write it again altho you've already counted it.

Take into account this string: *"I took something that took guts to do"*, first you find *took*, you write that to the output file, later on.. *took* comes again and you write it yet again to the output file. To avoud this, you'll need to store "known words" somehow, an easy way to do this would be:

```
def repeat(fileIn, fileOut):
    knownWords = []
    with open(fileOut, 'w') as fileOut: # Normally, you don't reuse variable names like this..
        with open(fileIn, 'r') as fileIn:
            content = fileIn.read()
        for word in content.split(' '):
            if not word.lower() in knownWords and content.count(word) > 1:
                fileOut.write()
                knownWords.append(word.lower())
    return content
```

Or you could delay the output to the new file, which might be risky in certain scnearios where you need "real-time" writing to the new file, sort of like a stream.. But in this case i don't see any harm in doing:

```
def repeat(fileIn, fileOut):
    outputData = ''

    with open(fileIn, 'r') as fileIn:
        content = fileIn.read()

    for word in content.split(' '):
        if not word in outputData and content.count(word) > 1:
            outputData += word + ' '

    with open(fileOut, 'w') as fileOut:
        fileOut.write(outputData[:-1])

    return content
```